# best way to programmatically check for a failed scp in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script that I'm working on with this line of code that does a loop through local files (.gz) and does an scp. I want to test for a failed `scp` if possible. I am doing a loop so I can echo each file name to a log so I can keep track of it.

Can someone show me how to check for failed scp? or better yet, a good code example to do this?  Thanks for your help.

```
for gzfile in $LOCALDMPDIR/*.gz
do
  /usr/bin/scp -P 2222 -i $KEYFILE $gzfile foobar@$1:$TGTDIR
  echo "$gzfile is done. " 2>&1
done
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using the `-q` option to scp which prevents it from prompting for a password if the key is rejected by the remote server

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use $? to access the return value of the last command.  Check the man page for scp to verify, but I think a return value of zero means success.  A non-zero value means some kind of failure.

Comment: something like if `$? > 1 then echo "scp failed" `?

Comment: @jdamae: `if (($? > 0)); then echo "scp failed"; fi` (or `!=`) or `if [ $? -ne 0 ]`

Comment: My copy of scp regularly returns 1 after successfully sending a file fwiw, not sure why.

Answer (score 16):

use :

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "OK"</br>
else
    echo "NOK"</br>
fi
```

> there're blank after "[" and before "]".
>   don't surround $? and 0 with quotes

Comment: also if you just want to know if it fails, (you don't need the "OK" part), then you can use `ne` as your operator (not equals), e.g. `if [ $? -ne 0 ];`

Answer (score 4):

You can check the varaible `$?` to see the return code of `scp`. If it returns non-zero then an error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to capture the error to a log:

```
for gzfile in $LOCALDMPDIR/*.gz
do
  /usr/bin/scp -P 2222 -i $KEYFILE $gzfile foobar@$1:$TGTDIR 2>>/var/log/scperror.log \
  && echo "$gzfile is done." \
  || echo "scp error: $gzfile"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For the simpleminded like me out there who spent longer than normal messing with formatting errors:

```
scp "fromHere" hostname:"toThere"
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ];
then
    echo "SUCCESS"
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
```

Comment: There needs to be a space between [ and the next characters. (the single "[" is a shortcut for calling test). The above example gives me errors, so i had to insert a space.